# Back button pressed gives NullPointerException in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, handler

In my app I am using an activity `MainActivity` and using this activity I start `FragmentTransaction` which took me to need fragment screen name `Welcomescreen` and in `Welcomescreen` fragment i use handler to move to next fragment in fixed time interval.
The problem is when i press back button on `Welcomescreen` fragment to came out of app, it give me  `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

So why it is trowing `java.lang.NullPointerException` and how to remove this error??

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.gk;

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.LayoutParams;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        //private static final int CONTENT_VIEW_ID = 10101010;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);

                frame.setId(R.id.listcontainer);
                setContentView(frame, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


                if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    Welcomescreen welcome = new Welcomescreen();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.listcontainer, welcome);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Welcomescreen.java

```
package com.example.gk;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Welcomescreen extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,false);
        ImageView welcomeimage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.welome_image);
        welcomeimage.setOnClickListener(this);
        handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listcontainer, menu );
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();


            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 7000);
        return view;
    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.welome_image:
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listcontainer, menu );
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    }



}
```

Logcat:

```
10-08 14:26:51.195: W/dalvikvm(10252): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252): Process: com.example.gk, PID: 10252
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at com.example.gk.Welcomescreen$1.run(Welcomescreen.java:31)
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
10-08 14:26:51.197: E/AndroidRuntime(10252):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which line of code is represented by line 31?

Comment: @ThomasR.    `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();`   in Welcomescreen.java

Comment: Ok, then your fragmentmanager is null. Override the onActivityCreated() method and perform your fragment transaction code in there, without the handler and runnable stuff.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasR.

Comment: @ThomasR. I must need to move to next fragment in fixed time interval so i need to use handler and runnable.

Comment: Ok, then implement with handler like I suggested and block the back handling as long as the handler was not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please add below code in **Welcomescreen Fragment** ?

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you press back button activity gets (paused|stopped|destroyed) and object reference of activity then refer to null pointer. The thread running in `Welcomescreen` fragment, needs activity reference but that is null.

Check comment in following code:

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); // This line will throw exception as getFragmentManager() method uses activity reference.
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listcontainer, menu );
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


        } 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that all interaction between fragments will be through the container activity.

1. Save a reference to the welcome activity in the on attach of the welcome fragment.
2. Create a public method in the activity which changes the current
   fragment, then call this method in your fragment (depends on the
   click\time interval).
3. In this method call the logic of the fragment manager to change the current fragment.

You can also achieve this behaviour by implementing an interface which change the fragment and decouple the connection to the welcome activity.